# Browser wasting time between loading of resources?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, google-chrome-devtools, page-load-time

I'm trying to understand what's going on between the HTML page load and the request of a deferred external resource through Javascript.

Tested on local (no DNS lookup required)

[image]

Why it seems like the browser is wasting "a lot of time" without doing anything?

My page is empty. It only contains the HTML, HEAD and BODY skeleton and the required Javascript code to call jQuery after page load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Demo

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload(){
      var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var s = document.createElement("script"); s.async = true;
      s.src = "jquery.min.js"
      b.appendChild(s);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener){
      window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    }else if (window.attachEvent){
      window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    }else{
      window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it because the `onload` event takes some time to get triggered?

Comment: I couldn't replicate this, it was only stalled for 2ms rather than your 200+, using Chrome 63.0.3239.132 Win10 64-bit Pro, is it a local web server or are you just using the html file within your browser directly?

Comment: Within my browser. I do not always get such a big difference between them, but there's always some difference with a blank space.

Comment: IIRC that red line you're seeing it the `onload` event, so yes that took some 250ms after the html page was requested. Why it took that long I cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it, but here are some ways to investigate further.

### Load Performance Recording

[Record page load performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#record-load). Line up the **Network** chart with the **Main** chart to map network requests to main thread activity. Maybe the CPU is maxed out doing some work (a Chrome extension, perhaps), which is delaying the `load` event. See [Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) to get familiar with the UI (that tutorial covers runtime perf, but the load perf UI is the same).

### Real User Monitoring metrics

Instrument the code using the [User Timing API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/) or [Navigating Timing attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#sec-navigation-timing-interface) to further measure when the script starts running, when the load event listener fires, etc.

Let me know if these help!